# Replacing navbar class based on screen size

Tags: javascript, nav

## Question

How can I swap classes of my navbar using javascript.

### Background

I have a fixed navbar that I am trying to change to a static navbar on smaller screen sizes (< 768px) because my mobile menu pusher is having layout problems due to the fixed nav.

### HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mynav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
   controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

I tried creating a javascript function to add / remove the static nav class but for some reason it's not working.

### JS

```
function changeNav() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("#mynav").addClass("navbar-static-top");
        $("#mynav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    } else {
        $("#mynav").removeClass("navbar-static-top");
        $("#mynav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
    }
}
changeNav();
```

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead, this is propper and have better performances:

```
let lastState = false;
function checkForViewportChange () {
    var state = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches;
    if (state != lastState) {
        if (state) {
            //do your stuff here
        } else {
            //do your other stuff here
        }
        lastState = state
}}

window.setInterval (checkForViewportChange, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check every time user resizes the screen, use .resize() method

Ex.

```
$(window).resize(() => {
    let b = $(window).width() < 768;
    $("#mynav").addClass("navbar-"+(b ? "static":"fixed")+"-top");
    $("#mynav").removeClass("navbar-"+(b ? "fixed":"static")+"-top");
});
```

Comment: can you add an example, otherwise this might be better as a comment

Comment: Yes sure. See the answer again

Answer (score -1):

This is probably easier done with [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) than javascript.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    // styles for device width <= 768px 
}
```

If you really want to use javascript, then the answer from Abdeslem Charif is a good start

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Since it doesn't seem you can change classes with media queries, how do you suggest I accomplish the static nav change like this?

Comment: This is a very helpful comment, since it is not in scope though this should not be an answer.